# Limiting a results Flickr Api to avoid duplicate photos from a user?

Tags: php, api, flickr

Trying to output flickr images from a certain location, not using any geolocation yet, only the a string of the location, but thats a problem for another topic :).

Problem is that when I call flickr.photos.search for that place, I may get a few results from a single user. Is there any easy way in PHP to limit this, but still maintain the number of images I request?

Rather than having the output populated with a few users, I would like to have 12 images each  by different users. I know this is easily possible, but its on the tip of my brain and I cant seem to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have far.

` 
$users = array();

```
foreach($rsp->photos->photo as $photo)
{
    $photo_owner = $photo["owner"];
    $photo_id = $photo['id'];
    $photo_title = $photo['title'];
    $photo_url = "http://flickr.com/photos/" . $photo_owner . "/" . $photo_id . "/";
    $flickr_getSizes = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&api_key=$api_key&photo_id=$photo_id";


    // If its not in an array, add it and output the image
    if (!in_array($photo_owner, $users)){

        array_push($users, $photo_owner);

        $flickr_getSizes = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&api_key=$api_key&photo_id=$photo_id";
        $sizes_rsp = getXML($flickr_getSizes);

        foreach($sizes_rsp->sizes->size as $size){

            if ($size['label'] == $preferredSize) {
                echo '<li>';
                echo '<a href="' . $photo_url . '"><img src="' . $size['source'] .'"/></a>';
                echo '<h3><a href="' . $photo_url . '">' . $p_title . '</a></h3>';
                echo '</li>';

            }

        }

    }

}`
```

There is more above but its only getting the XML.

Comment: hi! have you found out an answer to this question?